# Using Handlebars util methods in Meteor server

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm working on my first Meteor app, and I'm trying to escape a string on the server side. I was hoping to use Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression, but even when I add handlebars (which I had to do, even though Meteor already uses it?), I still get

```
ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

error when that code is hit. Is there a way to invoke that method server side without manually including the source in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor uses Handlebars on the client only. [Server-side rendering is on the roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering).

Also, the Handlebars that comes with Meteor doesn't include Utils.

Use `{{{thingThatNeedsEscaping}}}` instead, [as per the documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) that unescapes it.

Also, I don't think it's necessary to escape stuff before inserting it into the database, if you want it though there are other JS functions for that (like [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1269037) variants that are not deprecated).